# How to remove appended elements one by one using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove the appended elements one by one using javascript. I know how to remove the whole list but I want to remove the appended one by one on every time when I click on remove button which I don't know how to solve it till now.

here is a quick demo of what's happening when I click remove button:-

http://jsfiddle.net/0ojjt9Lu/

javascript code:-

```js
$(window).on('pageinit', function() {
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Sadd").click(function() {
        var lastId = $("#modules h1").length;
        var $newLabel = $("#module-1-label").clone();
        var $newSc = $("#module-1-scredit").clone();
        var $newSgrade = $("#module-1-sgrade").clone();
        $newLabel.html("<h1>Module " + (lastId+1) + ":</h1>");
        $newSc.find("label").attr("for", "Sc"+(lastId+1));
        $newSc.find("input").attr("name", "Sc"+(lastId+1)).attr("id", "Sc"+(lastId+1));
        $newSgrade.find("label").attr("for", "Sgrade"+(lastId+1));
        $newSgrade.find("select").attr("name", "Sgrade"+(lastId+1)).attr("id", "Sgrade"+(lastId+1));
        $("#modules").append($newLabel, $newSc, $newSgrade);
  
        $("#Sremove").click(function() {
         $("#module-1-label").last().remove()
   $("#module-1-scredit").last().remove()
   $("#module-1-sgrade").last().remove()
     
     });
    });
  });
 });
```

Update:- I'm able to remove items that were appended but that includes Module 1 and it's removing in reverse order

e.g:- 8 modules (1,2,3, etc) it will remove first 1 and 6 then it will remove 7 then 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind the click event for remove module button, every time add the module. So please bind the click event once.

Use below code.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Sadd").click(function() {
    var lastId = $("#modules h1").length;
    var $newLabel = $("#module-1-label").clone();
    var $newSc = $("#module-1-scredit").clone();
    var $newSgrade = $("#module-1-sgrade").clone();
    $newLabel.html("<h1>Module " + (lastId+1) + ":</h1>");
    $newSc.find("label").attr("for", "Sc"+(lastId+1));
    $newSc.find("input").attr("name", "Sc"+(lastId+1)).attr("id", "Sc"+(lastId+1));
    $newSgrade.find("label").attr("for", "Sgrade"+(lastId+1));
    $newSgrade.find("select").attr("name", "Sgrade"+(lastId+1)).attr("id", "Sgrade"+(lastId+1));
    $("#modules").append($newLabel, $newSc, $newSgrade);
 });
 $("#Sremove").click(function() {
   var lastId = $("#modules h1").length;
   if(lastId > 5){
      var lastLi = $("#modules h1").last().closest("li");
      var lastLi2 = lastLi.next("li");
      var lastLi3 = lastLi2.next("li");
      lastLi.remove();
      lastLi2.remove();
      lastLi3.remove();   
    }
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0ojjt9Lu/4/)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Ok this works fine but the problem is that it will remove the whole appended modules instead of remove module by module like my demo

Comment: Please check the fiddle link. It remove module by module only.

Comment: well that's the problem it works in the fiddle link only

Comment: I already mentioned you bind the click event for **Sremove** button every time adding the module  in **sadd** button click. Please bind the click event one time. Like above code snippet.

Comment: Yeah it was mistake I forgot to bind the click event thanks again for helping

Answer (score 0):

Hi Shihab Now used to this Jquery code

**[.last()](https://api.jquery.com/last/)** and **[.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** jquery code

```
$("#Sremove").click(function() {
    var lastLi = $("#modules li").last();
    var lastLi2 = lastLi.closest();
      var lastLi3 = lastLi2.closest();

      lastLi.remove();
      lastLi2.remove();
      lastLi3.remove();

    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0ojjt9Lu/3/)**

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0ojjt9Lu/5/)**

Comment: is there a possible way to remove the three list items at the same time and I don't want the items to be deleted from module 1 to 5

Comment: @Shihab Yes it's posible but if you change your  html code than it's possible now first you create only ul than clone to ul and remove only ul